# Magento 2 - receive XML in post data (API)

Tags: magento2

In my store, I need to build `Soap API`, which accepts XML data from 3rd party solution, parses it and creates new customer based on provided data.

My questions is how can I get XML from post body data?

Thanks!

Comment: can you help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296960/how-to-fetch-post-method-xml-data-in-magento2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just capture the XML in Controller's execute function.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't. Create separate service that is going to do that using Magento framework (check Customer or Catalog module for guidance). Because your request at the moment looks like you're going wrong way.